# Docusign : Signature Verification and Online viewer

Tags: digital-signature, docusignapi, verification

I have requirement to use docusign to send documents for sign.

I have gone through the documentation of api of it but could not found way for below requirement:

1. Signature Verification
2. Online viewer/editing

Does docusign provide these functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) When you create an electronic signature you get a unique id that is encrypted, documentable and tamper-evident.
You can set your electronic signature verification preferences such as time stamp, digital certificate and more. Signer authentication options include identity verification via email address, SMS text message, phone call, unique access codes, and more.

2) You can only make changes to a DocuSign document when the sender enables you to use the Mark Up feature. If the feature is enabled, you can:
"White out" or cover up document text to indicate deletions.
Cover up text and add new text over the old text.
Add new text in a blank region of the document.

You cannot alter the document once it is signed for obvious reasons.

The following file formats are supported
DocuSign supports the following file types:

DOCUMENT    .as, .asl, .asp, .doc, .docm, .docx, .dot, .dotm, .dotx, .htm, .html, .pdf, .pdx, .rtf, .txt, .wpd, .wps, .wpt

DRAWING .dwg, .dxf, .emz, .svg, .svgz, .vdx, .vsd, .vss, .vst

IMAGE   .bmp, .cdr, .dcx, .gif, .ico, .jpg, .jpeg, .pct, .pic, .png, .rgb, .sam, .tga, .tif, .tiff, .wpg

PRESENTATION    .dps, .dpt, .pot, .potx, .pps, .ppt, .pptm, .pptx

SPREADSHEET .csv, .et, .ett, .xls, .xlsx, .xlt